# Unable to derive Xpath syntax for radio buttons without any distinguished value inside div tag

Tags: selenium, xpath, automation

I want to click a radio button out of 10 radio buttons on a webpage but each radio button tag is exactly same inside Div/INPUT tag, i.e for each radio button  values are exactly same and hence not able to derive a xpath to click on it. Can't use contains text to levarage radio button name as radio button name is in different SPAN tag so can't use that as a reference, Please help me: below is the code :

```
<div class="classname">
<input name="category.value" type="radio" class="classname">
</input>
<span class="classname">Radio button Name</span>
```

Comment: Can you try //span[text()='radio button name']/preceding-sibling::input|1]

Comment: Thanks @RichEdwards: but thats also not working, May be I need to ask help from one of the dev, initially it had a value but suddenly since 2 days that value is not seen when inspecting and my already running test case gone for toss, as it says not able to find element (obvious)

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='classname']/input[@value=1]").click()`

Your HTML must have some kind of return type, maybe `value` or `name`. I belive you can use that.

Comment: I wish !! But thats not the case, it has only name as category.value but corresponding value to distinguish from one radio button to another is not present thats what makes it confusing !! appreciate for your feedback Anupam.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned in the comments can you please try:

```
//span[text()='Radio button Name']/preceding-sibling::input[1]
```

Not that this is case sensitive.

This works based on the html provided:

[image: working xpath]

If it doesn't work for you can you please verify your HTML. There are lots of other ways of getting the element. If you need to modify the html just do it and let us know :-)